# Find and copy folders recursively but keep the structure

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

My problem: I've got two folders, i.e., `~/foo` and `~/bar`. Both have got the same structure like `~/[foo/bar]/subdir1` and `~/[foo/bar]/subdir2` and inside these subdirectories in `foo` are folders like `.svn/`

I want to copy these `.svn` folders to the same place but in `bar`. Therefore I already tried:

```
find -name .svn -exec cp -R {} ~/bar/ \;
```

**Note:** The command was executed in `~/foo/`

Unfortunately this command neither copies any files nor gives me an error message. So what am I doing wrong and what is the solution for my problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `-p` option in `cp` . It preserves everything (including structure) by default.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense that your command doesn’t copy any files. It should copy all the `~/foo/…/.svn` directories into `~/bar/.svn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd` into `foo` and run

```
find . -name .svn -type d -exec sh -c 'for arg do echo cp -R "$arg" ../bar/"$arg"; done' sh {} +
```

It will invoke the `echo` command for each `.svn` directory under `foo`
and produce output like this:

```
cp -R ./subdir1/.svn ../bar/./subdir1/.svn
cp -R ./subdir2/.svn ../bar/./subdir2/.svn
```

Verify that this is correct —
you can replace `../bar` with `~/bar` if you want —
and then run the `find` command again without the `echo`:

```
find . -name .svn -type d -exec sh -c 'for arg do cp -R "$arg" ../bar/"$arg"; done' sh {} +
```

This will actually copy the directories.