# Translating Windows script for use in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, script, shell-script

I have this batchfile that I use in Windows that I would like to translate into a Linux script. Could anyone help with that? Here is the script and the attempt at a Linux version. I did not write this, someone helped me.

The purpose is to run a python command "manual.py" which converts any file that is not an MP4 into an MP4 with FFmpeg. I have it running as a scheduled task in Windows against a mapped Linux share; however, I would rather just have the script run on the Linux box. 
My Linux scripting skills are, well, non-existent.

This works

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
Set Location="z:\movies"

Set PatternName=".*\.mp4 .*\srt"

Set Transcoder="c:\sysinternals\mp4auto\"

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir %Location% /s /b /a-d ^| findstr /v /i /e /r %PatternName%') do (%Transcoder%manual.py -i "%%F" -a
)
```

This does not.

```
!#/bin/sh

Location="/TV Shows/*/*"
Pattern="*.mp4"
Transcode = /Mp4auto/manual.py

for Convert in (find $Location -type f \( -iname "*.*" ! -iname $Pattern \))
do

$Transcode -i $Convert -a
done
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- The first two characters of a shell script should be `#!`, not `!#`.

Assuming that you have elected to use a POSIX-type shell
(which is a good choice):

- When you assign to a variable,
  there must be no space before or after the `=`.
- When you *use* (*refer to*) a variable,
  you should almost always put it into quotes. 
  (What we often say is that you should always quote shell variables
  unless you have a good reason not to,
  and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.)
- You are running the `find` command,
  and taking its output and using it as part of a larger command. 
  You put the `find` command into parentheses. 
  You need to put it into `$(`…`)`.
- But this is a bad way to do that,
  and will fail if any pathnames contain space(s). 
  And so it will blow sky-high, because *all* your pathnames
  will contain space(s), because your directory name is `"/TV Shows"`.

I’ll get back to this.

- The first argument to `find` should generally be the name of a directory. 
  This is a gross oversimplification — there are lots of variations —
  but the point is that you should be giving `find`
  an argument of `"/TV Shows"`. 
  You don’t need to specify `"/TV Shows/*/*"`;
  `find` will find all files under the `"/TV Shows"` directory.
- If you want to look at only two levels of directories, say so.

Other notes:

- Your BAT file uses the `.*\srt` pattern. 
  But you have not explained the significance of this,
  nor made any attempt to translate it into your shell script.
- You use `-iname "*.*"` in your `find` command in your shell script. 
  This matches all files *that have a* **`.`** in their names. 
  (This character is known as “period”, “full stop” and “dot”.) 
  Not all Unix files have a period in their name,
  so this is not the same as matching all files. 
  This is the right thing to do
  if you want to exclude files that don’t have a dot in their names. 
  I point this out because
- People transitioning from Windows
  are accustomed to thinking that `*.*` means all files.
- People new to Unix (and `find`, in particular)
  sometimes believe that they need to say `-name "*"` or something similar
  to get all files, and then start specifying exclusions. 
  That’s not needed; `find` finds *all* files by default.
- You didn’t specify a requirement
  to exclude files that don’t have a dot in their names.
- The script processes *all* files that have a dot in their name
  and don’t end with `.mp4`. 
  This could potentially include `.py` files, `.txt` files, and whatever. 
  It’s probably safer to search for the types of files
  that can be converted to MP4.

So, if you’re willing to rename your directory to `TV_Shows`,
and you can guarantee that none of your file names contain space,
then this should get you started:

```
#!/bin/sh

Location="/TV_Shows"
Pattern="*.mp4"
Transcode=/Mp4auto/manual.py

for Convert in $(find "$Location" -type f \( -iname "*.*" ! -iname "$Pattern" \))
do
    "$Transcode" -i "$Convert" -a
done
```

A better approach, which handles pathnames containing spaces,
is to use `find`’s ability to run a command on each file that it finds:

```
#!/bin/sh

Location="/TV Shows"
Pattern="*.mp4"
Transcode=/Mp4auto/manual.py

find "$Location" -type f \( -iname "*.*" ! -iname "$Pattern" \) -exec "$Transcode" -i {} -a ';'
```

You can split that long command into two lines with a `\` (backslash):

```
find "$Location" -type f \( -iname "*.*" ! -iname "$Pattern" \) \
                        -exec "$Transcode" -i {} -a ';'
```

I just noticed that the OP asked a follow-up question:

> could you give me an example
> of just converting any file with .mkv or .avi as the extension

Use `-o`, which means “or” in `find`:

```
    ︙
Pattern1="*.mkv"
Pattern2="*.avi"
    ︙

find "$Location" -type f \( -iname "$Pattern1" -o -iname "$Pattern2" \) \
                        -exec "$Transcode" -i {} -a ';'
```

Comment: so the directory is actually tvshows, no spaces. All I want to exclude is .mp4 and .srt files. The linux script was actually written by someone else, and he admitted it was probably wrong, he wrote the batch file that works in windows. I was just trying to get the windows batch file translated to work in linux. Some of the files will contain spaces, they are tv shows renamed by filebot, or sonarr. How do I change the pattern variable to exclude .mp4 and .srt?

Comment: so @Scott, instead of excluding could you give me an example of just converting any file with .mkv or .avi as the extension. The directory tvshows has no spaces, but under that there are hundreds of subdirectories with show names and seasons and they all have spaces.