# Bash script to find folders containing a specific subfolder, and then copying to new directory while preserving parent name

Tags: linux, bash, script

I'll try to be as specific as possible. I have a `Packages` folder containing subfolders with various names, but in each of those subfolders there will always be a `dist` folder. I want to find the folders containing `dist`, and then move/copy *only* `dist` and its parent folder to a new directory.

Example:

Current path structure is as below:

```
~/Documents/Packages/core-types/dist
~/Documents/Packages/graphql-utils/dist
~/Documents/Packages/manuscript-assets/dist
```

NOTE: `core-types`, `graphql`, etc., all contain subfolders in addition to `dist`; otherwise this would be much more straightforward...

I am trying set it up so that when these paths are migrated to a new directory, 
say, `~/Documents/Artifacts/`, it will look like:

```
~/Documents/Artifacts/core-types/dist
~/Documents/Artifacts/graphql-utils/dist
~/Documents/Artifacts/manuscript-assets/dist
```

Here's the script I hacked together in case someone can offer guidance:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ~/Documents/Packages -name dist -print \
| sort -u \
      | while read olddir
        do 
          moveto="~/Documents/Artifacts/$(echo \"$olddir\" | cut -d\/ -f 6)"
          mv "$olddir" "$moveto"
        done
```

There has to be a better way to accomplish this...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t mean to be flippant, but you have two issues:

1. Identifying the subdirectories named `dist`, and
2. moving or copying them into the `Artifacts` directory.

This is quite a bit easier if we use relative pathnames. 
If you absolutely need to use absolute pathnames (har har), say so.

Here are two ways to do step 1
(identifying the subdirectories named `dist`):

#### `find`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/Documents/Packages &&
find . -name dist -type d -exec sh -c 'for d do parent="${d%/*}"; \
                                                mkdir -p "../Artifacts/$parent"; \
                                                mv "$d" "../Artifacts/$parent"; done' \
                                                sh {} +
```

(You can put the `find` command all on one line if you want.) 
This goes into `~/Documents/Packages`, so we can use relative pathnames. 
A fairly straightforward use of the `-name` and `-type` tests
of `find` to identify (sub)directories named `dist`. 
Use the `-exec` action to pass their names to a miniature shell script.

The script loops over its arguments. 
For each one, it identifies the parent directory
by removing `/` and a pathname level from the right. 
For example, the parent of `./core-types/dist` is `./core-types`. 
(Remember; we are *in* `~/Documents/Packages` and looking at **`.`**,
so we are seeing relative pathnames.) 
I could have said `parent="${d%/dist}"`, but I wanted to keep it generic. 
Create the destination/parent directory —
for example, `../Artifacts/./core-types`. 
(The extra `./` is ignored; `/./` acts like `/`,
so this creates `../Artifacts/core-types`, which is `~/Documents/Packages/../Artifacts/core-types`,
which is `~/Documents/Artifacts/core-types`.) 
We then move the `dist` directory into that directory.

#### bash Pathname Expansion

This depends on a feature of bash that is not present in all shells. 
(For that matter, it might not be in *all* versions of bash.)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Documents/Packages && shopt -s globstar &&
for d in **/dist/; do d="${d%/}"; parent="${d%/*}";
                                  mkdir -p "../Artifacts/$parent";
                                  mv "$d" "../Artifacts/$parent"; done
```

Set the `globstar` shell option (`shopt`),
which causes `**` to do a recursive search. 
Then loop through `**/dist/`. 
If we said `**/dist`,
that would find all *files and* directories named `dist`;
adding the `/` at the end constrains the search to (sub)directories only. 
For each one, execute a bunch of commands.

`**/dist/` gives us the directory names in the form `core-types/dist/`
(with the `/` at the end, as we specified). 
`d="${d%/}"` strips off that trailing slash. 
The rest of the code is the same.

Note: this will not look under top-level directories
whose names begin with **`.`** (e.g., `~/Documents/Packages/.memories/dist`)
unless you add the `dotglob` option.

### Step 2

If you want to copy instead of move,
just change `mv` to `cp -R` in either of the above commands.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if  you try using if (cat /Documents/package/**/*/dist)
                     then mv or cp

Comment: -1. Answers should be specific and clear. This one seems cryptic first, then one notices that it simply makes no sense. E.g. `cat`-ing directories in Linux [doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154119/108618).